# How to move the parent window in Child window?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

Currently, I use:

```
::SendMessage(GetParent(),WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,HTCAPTION,0);
```

to put the parent window in moving and sizing modal, but this has some side effects. so i'm looking for another way to let the parent go into the moving and sizing modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Pass `SC_MOVE` as the wParam value and 0 or -1 as the lParam value.